# Unable to remove child viewcontroller after Navigation

Tags: ios, swift, uipopovercontroller

I have added a child viewcontroller to VC1. On tapping a button in child viewcontroller , I am pushing to another viewcontroller , VC2. On tapping back button in VC2 , I need to remove the child viewcontroller but I m unable to do it.Can u pls help me ?

```
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {

        let controller = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PopupViewController") as! PopupViewController
        controller.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
        controller.view.removeFromSuperview()
        controller.removeFromParentViewController()
 }
```

Comment: where is your back button action ? Can you show that.

Comment: you are missing: super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

Comment: That is navigation bar's default back button

Comment: @SuganyaMarlin In compliance with the code, you are instantiating a new view controller instead of removing the controller already present in memory. let controller = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PopupViewController") as! PopupViewController  This line of code creates a new instance (a new allocated object)

Comment: ya u r correct...I have fixed and posted the solution@soumil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added the following in VC1 and it solved my problem

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {

    for controllers in self.childViewControllers
    {
        controllers.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
        controllers.view.removeFromSuperview()
        controllers.removeFromParentViewController()
    }

}
```